# Count how many users have both month A and B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count how many `users` have both `january` and `february` months. I have a `users` table with this structure and data:

```
id                         | 1
user                       | u1
month                      | january

id                         | 2
user                       | u1
month                      | february

id                         | 3
user                       | u2
month                      | january
```

In my example the response would be 1.
I've tried doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.month = 'january') s1 LEFT JOIN users s2 ON s1.user = s2.user AND s2.month = 'february';`

In my actual data set this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE users.month = 'january'` returns about 100 so the overall selection can not possibly be larger than this result, yet the result is way higher.

I'm sure the answer is very simple, however i'm not very proficient in SQL so i just don't know what part of the documentation i should be reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.user
      from t
      where t.month in ('january', 'february')
      group by t.user
      having count(distinct t.month) = 2
     ) t;
```

If there is at most one row per user per month, then a `join` might have better performance:

```
select count(*)
from t tj join
     t tf
     on tj.user = tf.user and
        tj.month = 'january' and
        tf.month = 'february';
```

If you can have duplicates, then `count(distinct user)` is needed.

Comment: I believe the fist query is the thing i'm looking for. The second one's not returning the correct number with or without distinct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select count(distinct user)
from tablename t
where t.month in ('january', 'february')
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename where user = t.user and month > t.month
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mM2qrTd2883ncZ8LZaJQM2/0).